# Airflow 2.x.x | Dynamically create TriggerDagRunOperator based on previous component response with dynamic task mapping

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a Parent DAG that has 2 components. task_a should call external REST API and get the child DAGs details(DAG ID and parameters). Based on task_a response, task_b should trigger the child DAG.

[image: Components]

Sample task_a response:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'dag_id': 'child_1', 'params': {'test': 'test1'}},
    {'id': 2, 'dag_id': 'child_2', 'params': {'test': 'test2'}}, 
    {'id': 3, 'dag_id': 'child_3', 'params': {'test': 'test3'}}
]
```

based on the  above, I want to create **TriggerDagRunOperator** like in below DAG

```
import logging
import sys

import airflow
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.variable import Variable
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.decorators import task
import requests
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.decorators import task, task_group

# from airflow.decorators import dag, dag_run_trigger

doc_md = """
## Purpose
This DAG will fetch pipeline details from pipeline master table and trigger downstream pipelines dynamically.
"""

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="core_forecasting_automated_ml_pipeline",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    doc_md=doc_md
) as dag:

    @task
    def task_a():
        api_url = 'https://<external_host>/get_pipelines'
        response = requests.get(api_url)
        return response.json()

    @task
    def task_b(dag_info):
        child_dag_trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id=f'trigger_sub_dags',
            trigger_dag_id=dag_info['dag_id'],
            conf=dag_info['params'],
            wait_for_completion=True,
            poke_interval=20,
            allowed_states=['success'],
            dag=dag
        )
        child_dag_trigger
 

    dag_info = task_a()
    dag_info >> task_b.expand(dag_info=dag_info)
```

Above code is not triggering the child dags.

Airflow Version: v2.5.3

1. I want to know how to dynamically map **TriggerDagRunOperator** and pass **trigger_dag_id** and **conf** values to the operator
2. Is there any equivalent decorator for TriggerDagRunOperator?

UPDATE: I get the below error when I dynamically map **trigger_dag_id** value

```
    Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/automated_ml.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/decorators/task_group.py", line 97, in _create_task_group
    retval = self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/automated_ml.py", line 95, in dynamic_tg
    trigger_dag_id= dag_info['dag_id'] if not dag_info['dag_id'] else '',
TypeError: 'MappedArgument' object is not subscriptable
```

Approach 2:
I tried using dynamic task mapping approach but I am unable to pass trigger_dag_id value in runtime. Airflow is expecting trigger_dag_id to be static and not accepting dynamic value.

```
TriggerDagRunOperator.partial(
        task_id='triger_child_dags',
        wait_for_completion=True,
        poke_interval=20,
        allowed_states=['success'],
    ).expand(
        trigger_dag_id=pipeline_info['dag_id], # cannot pass str value. Airflow expecting list or dict value 
        conf=pipeline_info,
    )
```

Comment: Were you able to make your use case works by any chance ?